# How to SELECT a filtered result of logins of users?

Tags: mysql

This is my `logins` SQL table:

```
id | user | time | ip
```

Example data:

```
id | user | time       | ip
1    5      1352100506   80.87.208.133
```

I have already about ~ 50 000 rows in this table, so I want to filter it out.

Instead of erasing old entries, I'd like to keep some of them. I want to:

1) keep every unique IP every user has used
2) keep the latest (max) time for every such IP

So from this dataset:

```
id user time ip
1  1    1350000000 1.1.1.1
2  1    1350000001 1.1.1.1
3  1    1350000002 1.1.1.1
4  1    1350000003 1.1.1.2
5  1    1350000004 1.1.1.3
```

I'd like to have this select/result:

```
id user time ip
3  1    1350000002 1.1.1.1
4  1    1350000003 1.1.1.2
5  1    1350000004 1.1.1.3
```

This is my current query, however I'm not sure I'm doing this right:

```
SELECT `id`, `user`, MAX(`time`), `ip`
FROM `logins`
GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
```

**Why I think the query is not correct:**

Because when I do this test query:

```
SELECT `id`, `user`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`), FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(`time`)), `ip`
FROM `logins`
WHERE `user` = 1
GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
```

The values for `time` and `` MAX(`time`) `` are different, yet the `id` values are the same. How is this possible?

This is my PMA result:

[image]

So I'm wondering what does my query actually return. Does it return what I want (**every unique IP of every user only once with the latest time for every such an IP**) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT l.`id`, x.`user`, x.`maxtime`, x.`ip` FROM 
    `logins` l,
    (SELECT `user`, MAX(`time`) as `maxtime`, `ip` FROM 
        `logins` GROUP BY `user`, `ip`) x 
    WHERE l.`user` = x.`user` AND l.`ip` = x.`ip` AND l.`time` = x.`maxtime`;
```

It's similar to yours, but the number of subqueries is lower.

Comment: This takes 10 seconds more than my query and for some reason returns a bit more results. This is strange ...

Comment: Well, this really seems to be the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardRodriguez Did it really take more time to evaluate? I'm making some tests with random data at SQLFiddle and it seems to be a little faster (for 354 rows, this one evaluates in about 32 ms, while the other evaluates in about 37 ms).The reason why it's showing more results, I guess, is that the table has registered two accesses at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I solved it with the following, however I'm sure there's a better way:

```
SELECT `user`, MAX(`time`) as `maxtime`, `ip`,

(
    SELECT `id`
    FROM (SELECT * FROM `logins`) as `a`
    WHERE `a`.`user` = `logins`.`user`
    AND `a`.`ip` = `logins`.`ip`
    AND `a`.`time` = MAX(`logins`.`time`)
) as `id`

FROM `logins`
GROUP BY `user`, `ip`
```